# Colorplot in Julia with awkward data format

Tags: plot, julia

I have data in the form of a list of tuples (x,y,z) with no particular ordering on the (x,y) values. I want to make a color plot in the x-y plane where z is represented by a color, using the PyPlot function

```
pcolor
```

The issue is this function accepts data in the format arr_x,arr_y,image where arr_x and arr_y are 1D arrays and image is a 2d Array such that image[i,j] corresponds here to the z value for x=arr_x[i],y=arr_y[j].

Is there a simple way to do this (without constructing the 2D array image, which would be annoying).

Answer (score 0):

Are you looking for `scatter`?

```
using Plots, Unzip # Unzip to go from list of tuples to tuple of lists
data = [(randn(), randn(), randn()) for _ in 1:200] # list of (x,y,z) tuples
x, y, z = unzip(data) # get vectors out of the tuple
scatter(x, y, zcolor=z)
```

will output [image]

Comment: not quite, as this leaves parts of the plot uncolored, unlike pcolor. I am trying to visualize a field of which I have a finite sampling.

Comment: So you are looking for some interpolation/extrapolation first. Two candidate packages to do that are https://github.com/JuliaEarth/GeoStats.jl and https://github.com/gher-ulg/DIVAnd.jl.